# Join terraria server using ip address on mobile version

Tags: terraria-mobile, hosting, server-administration

I'm running a terraria server and would like to be able to join the world I am running via the mobile version of the game (running on Android). Is it possible to join via the mobile version using the server's ip address? So far I haven't found an option in the mobile game ui but I may be missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got word in the discord channel for tshock that this isn't possible. Oh well. Maybe I'll setup the game on desktop and join there.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to join a server through direct IP.

For example:
My friend is playing *Terraria* and wants me to join him, but we are in different places.
To join him/her you need to go to settings, find VPN, and as a VPN server IP enter his/her router's IP.
Then you should be able to see his/her game just like if you were playing on same WI-FI.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Arqade is different from a forum, in that answers should be used to answer the original question, not for discussion or to ask for more information. If you have a new question you can search the site to see if it has already been answered, or if not ask it using the "Ask  a question" button in the top right. Consider taking the [tour] to learn more about how the site works.

Comment: @Malco But this is an answer. I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @Wrigglenite You are correct, I must have misread/misunderstood it the first time round. I have made some minor rewording/grammar corrections to make it a bit clearer, Maciej if you feel these are incorrect feel free to make further edits using the edit button.